# How to password protect a file in remote system using ansible?

Tags: ansible, command-line-interface

I'm trying to password protect a text file in a remote system, using mcrpyt or openssl, but these shell commands require a prompt for providing passwords. How do i make this possible using ansible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it using the openssl command

`echo -n "your-password" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in input -out output.enc -pass stdin`

To decrypt

`echo -n "your-password" | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in output.enc -out file -pass stdin`

Just write these commands in ansible and you can use the password from templates, where you can encrypt it using the ansible vault

For example

`echo -n "{{ password }}" | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in output.enc -out file -pass stdin`

You can get this passwrod as avariable from your var file which can be encrypted using ansible vault